# What does "no talloc stack frame..." mean?

Tags: 14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell XPS 13 9333.

Everytime I use the command line (succesfully or not) a short line is being put out instead of the usual fresh and empty line which you normally get if the command you used was succesfully processed. The line is always the same and it says:

```
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory
```

Any idea what this means?

Comment: indeed it is. But disabling password synch is not a option I think.

Comment: Why not? It is only used for Samba servers, so you only have to change your password at one place. You can still manually keep it in sync using `passwd` **and** `smbpasswd`, until the bug is fixed (LP [#1257186](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1257186)).